# lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system

Tags: privileges, lsof, fuse

What exactly is happening here?

```
root@bob-p7-1298c:/# ls -l /tmp/report.csv && lsof | grep "report.csv"
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1430 Dec  4 12:34 /tmp/report.csv
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

Comment: Are you getting this warning when you issue only `lsof` (without the `|` and grep)?

Comment: The same warning occurs either way, but just `lsof` outputs a large list of the open files. I think it is a side issue. I thought that maybe the file was held open by a process and that might have been the reason why root was unable to move the file, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Hence the confusion.

Comment: yeah, looks like the `can't stat...` is another issue. I assume the real problem is the `No such file or directory` error that you are getting. This might sound idiotic, but does the location /home/bob/Desktop exist?

Answer (score 52):

### FUSE and its access rights

`lsof` by default checks all mounted file systems including [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) - file systems implemented in user space which have special access rights in Linux.

As you can see in this [answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/23199/67132) a mounted [GVFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) file system (special case of FUSE) is normally accessible only to the user which mounted it (the owner of `gvfsd-fuse`). Even `root` cannot access it. To override this restriction it is possible to use mount options `allow_root` and `allow_other`. The option must be also enabled in the FUSE daemon which is described for example in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/401509/67132) ...but in your case you do not need to (and should not) change the access rights.

### Excluding file systems from lsof

In your case `lsof` does not need to check the GVFS file systems so you can exclude the `stat()` calls on them using the `-e` option (or you can just ignore the waring):

```
lsof -e /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

### Checking certain files by lsof

You are using `lsof` to get information about all processes running on your system and only then you filter the complete output using `grep`. If you want to check just certain files and the related processes use the `-f` option without a value directly following it then specify a list of files after the "end of options" separator `--`. This will be considerably faster.

```
lsof -e /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -- /tmp/report.csv
```

### General solution

To exclude all mounted file systems on which `stat()` fails you can run something like this (in `bash`):

```
x=(); for a in $(mount | cut -d' ' -f3); do test -e "$a" || x+=("-e$a"); done
lsof "${x[@]}" -f -- /tmp/report.csv
```

Or to be sure to use `stat()` (`test -e` could be implemented a different way):

```
x=(); for a in $(mount | cut -d' ' -f3); do stat --printf= "$a" 2>/dev/null || x+=("-e$a"); done
```

Answer (score 20):

`lsof` always tries to obtain some basic information about all filesystems, even if the arguments happen to imply that no result will come from a particular filesystem. If it's unable to access a filesystem (specifically, to call `stat` at its mount point, as the message says), it complains.

As root, you would normally have permission to access filesystems. However, due to the inner workings of [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), root does not automatically have all powers on a FUSE filesystem. This isn't a security feature (root can become the user who owns the filesystem and get access that way), it's a technical limitation.

GVFS-FUSE is a FUSE interface to [GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS), which is a mechanism that allows Gnome applications to access virtual filesystems implemented by Gnome plugins: GVFS grants non-Gnome applications access to these virtual filesystems via the regular filesystem interface.