# How to list QNAP virtual machines from an SSH command line?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, windows, samba, smb

This is partly a straight question and partly an attempt to gain more understanding about how QNAP network servers work.

My office uses a local network drive installed with (according to /proc/version) a Linux 3.2.26 QNAP build. While trying to sort out a [number of mishaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302395/ubuntu-immovable-tmp-file-on-network-drive-with-no-pid/302844) while our sysadmins were away, I learned that QNAP uses Samba/SMB.

When I was initially trying to find the device with avahi-discover to connect to it (I'm running Ubuntu 16.04), it showed up under "Microsoft Windows Network" (as well as "_qdiscover._tcp" and a few others). I'm not sure if that means that QNAP is running a Windows VM that's confusing Avahi, or if it's just offering up connection options to as many OSes as possible and the Windows one is just what Avahi happened to pick up on.

Is there a Linux command for determining this sort of thing? Or am I misunderstanding how this all works? I'm not a proper sysadmin but the two in our office are primarily Windows users, so having an understanding of the system is handy when I have to untangle something unusual between my machine and the network drive.

Comment: Use the QNAP web GUI for configuration. For example, do not edit the Samba configuration files directly as that way lies pain. Lots of it.

Comment: We don't always have access to the GUI, otherwise it would definitely be my first choice. :(

Answer (score 1):

In my QNAP NAS: ssh and

`virsh list --all`