# Can I restart systemd without rebooting?

Tags: rhel, systemd

I'm trying to restart services after a `yum update` on RHEL 7.4. I could restart every service using systemctl, but `needs-restarting` from `yum utils` tells me that I should also restart systemd itself:

```
# needs-restarting
1 : /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 21
```

**Can I restart `systemd` without rebooting the server, and how?**

I found a few mentions of `systemctl daemon-reload`, but this doesn't make it disappear from the needs-restarting list.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To restart the daemon, run

```
systemctl daemon-reexec
```

This is documented in [the `systemctl` manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html):

> Reexecute the systemd manager. This will serialize the manager state, reexecute the process
>              and deserialize the state again. This command is of little use except for debugging and
>              package upgrades. Sometimes, it might be helpful as a heavy-weight `daemon-reload`. While the
>              daemon is being reexecuted, all sockets systemd listening on behalf of user configuration will
>              stay accessible.

Unfortunately `needs-restarting` can’t determine that `systemd` has actually restarted. `systemd` `execs` itself to restart, which doesn’t reset the process’s start time; but `needs-restarting` compares the executable’s modification time with the process’s start time to determine whether a process needs to be restarted (among other things), and as a result it always considers that `systemd` needs to be restarted... To determine whether `systemd` really needs to be restarted, you can check the output of `lsof -p1 | grep deleted`: `systemd` uses a library, `libsystemd-shared`, which is shipped in the same package and is thus upgraded along with the daemon, so if `systemd` needs to be restarted you’ll see it using a deleted version of the library. If `lsof` shows no deleted files, `systemd` doesn’t need to be restarted. (Thanks to [Jeff Schaller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/117549/jeff-schaller) for the hint!)

Comment: Since the process will most likely be running with pid 1, the reboot will need to be executed.

Comment: @Raman, `daemon-reexec` is supposed to work even with `systemd` as pid 1.

Comment: The crux of needs-restarting boils down to https://github.com/rpm-software-management/yum/blob/master/utils.py#L132 where it queries the PID's "start_time"; if the daemon-reexec doesn't update that, needs-restarting will remain "confused".

Comment: Do not assume that any codepath involved is well-tested, especially on non-RedHat systems. It's technically possible to run daemon-reexec, but it's safer to reboot.

Comment: @Harald it’s used any time anyone upgrades `systemd` on Debian and derivatives, so it is well-tested. It’s also reasonably straightforward (look for [`do_reexecute`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/core/main.c)).

Comment: @StephenKitt - When i attempt to run `lsof -p1 | grep deleted` the following output is generated `lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs Output information may be incomplete`. In reading (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171519/lsof-warning-cant-stat-fuse-gvfsd-fuse-file-system), it appears that even root is unable to access it. What would the alternative be to `lsof -p1 | grep deleted`?

Comment: @Motivated nothing, you can ignore that in the context of this answer.

Comment: @StephenKitt - Nothing as there as there no other option and that there the warning output should be ignored?

Comment: @Motivated yes.

Comment: @StephenKitt - If i am ignoring the warning, it seems that i am unable to execute the command. Do you mean to say that since there is no other option, i should simply restart the device?

Comment: @Motivated no, I mean you should ignore the warning. Why would it mean that you can’t execute the command?

Comment: @StephenKitt - I meant to say that if i ignore the warning and don't resolve the issue, the command won't execute since it doesn't at the moment. In searching online, it suggests it can't be resolved (at least that's my understanding).

Comment: @Motivated it’s a warning, not an error, it doesn’t stop the command from executing. All it means is that `lsof` won’t provide information about files under `/run/user/1000/gvfs`. Since the point here is to check whether `systemd` is using a deleted version of a library, and neither systemd nor the libraries it uses live under `/run`, the fact that `lsof` can’t analyse anything under `/run/user/1000/gvfs` doesn’t alter the usefulness of the command for this purpose.

Comment: @StephenKitt - Thanks. That clarified my understanding. I have assumed that if it returns to the shell prompt, no deleted files were found. To clarify, what does -p1 refer to?

Comment: @StephenKitt - According to (https://serverfault.com/questions/805745/reboot-or-systemctl-daemon-reload-for-changes-to-etc-systemd-system-conf), it suggests that there is no requirement to run the command `systemctl daemon-reexec` as there is a scriplet included in package when `systemd` is upgraded.

Comment: @Motivated yes, and I alluded to that in the fifth comment under this answer. Some distributions restart `systemd` on upgrade, others don’t, my answer explains how to restart `systemd` and how to determine if it’s necessary in all cases.

Comment: @StephenKitt - Thanks Stephen. What does `-p1` refer to?

Comment: If you really are @Motivated, you should be able to figure that out from `man lsof`.

Comment: @StephenKitt - I did and the description in the man page isn't clear to me `excludes or selects the listing of files for the processes whose optional process IDentification (PID) numbers are  in  the  comma-separated  set  s  -  e.g.,  ``123''  or ``123,^456''.  (There should be no spaces in the set.)`. What does mean optional process whose identification numbers are comma-separated?

Comment: @Motivated hmm, I can see why it wouldn’t be all that clear... `-p` tells `lsof` to match processes whose pid corresponds to `-p`’s arguments, so 1 for `-p1` (and pid 1 is always the system’s init process, `systemd` when you use systemd), or 123 for `-p123`; the match can be negated using `^`, so `^456` matches all processes except pid 456, and multiple criteria can be specified by separating them with commas.

Comment: @StephenKitt - Thanks heaps. That's much clearer to me now.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, I had just upgraded `systemd` and any `systemctl` command was failing:

```
# systemctl daemon-reexec
Failed to reload daemon: Access denied
# systemctl status
Failed to read server status: Access denied
```

However according to the `init` manpage, you can do the same thing by sending `SIGTERM` to the daemon running as PID 1, which worked:

```
kill -TERM 1
```

This reloaded the daemon, after which all the `systemctl` commands started working again.